# Select en Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Quiero saber que estoy haciendo mal, soy realivamente nuevo usando Laravel y estoy haciendo una consulta que me arroja un error que cuando lo copio y pego en el mysql se ejecuta normal.
Esta es la consulta:

```
DB::table('premium_cierres')
                    ->whereRaw("CONCAT(anio_cierre, mes_cierre) >= EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM '$fechaInicio'")->latest()->paginate(10)
```

Ese es el error:
**Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `premium_cierres` where CONCAT(anio_cierre, mes_cierre) >= EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM '2019-03-19')**

**Muhas gracias pr su ayuda.**

Answer (score 0):

puedes ejecutarlo asi

```
DB::table('premium_cierres')
                    ->select(DB::raw("CONCAT(anio_cierre, mes_cierre) >= EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM '$fechaInicio'"))->latest()->paginate(10)
```

y modificar en config/database.php
'strict'=>false

espero y te ayude

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta, logré solucionarlo. Lo que pasa es que me había faltado añadir el paréntesis que cierre la función EXTRACT. Lo cerré y corrió muy bien. Espero le sirva a alguien.